# Unable to make USB drive letter stick

Tags: windows-xp, usb, usb-flash-drive

I am attempting to connect a Lacie USB external hard drive to a laptop with Windows XP SP3. It appears fine in Disk Management with an Active and Healthy partition but it does not have a drive letter.

If I assign a drive letter I can view the files by opening the partition from Disk Management. I can also access the drive from the Command Prompt. However, the partition does not appear in the Explorer, unless I log out and back in. Unfortunately, if I restart the computer the partition comes back without a drive letter again.

I've tried removing all the USB devices in the Device Manager and then reinstalling but the problem remains. I've also tried connecting to a different USB port. I have not yet tried attaching the drive to another computer.

What else should I try?

Comment: before you try anything, backup the files on that drive while you still have access.

Comment: I've seen similar behavior on a few machines (drive letter was assigned, but no program using Windows Shell - including Open File dialogs - would show the drive). It'd be cool to know what goes wrong there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get some help in these [USB Drive Troubleshooting notes](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtrouble_e.html).
The site has a lot of other USB Drive related notes and tools:
[USB Drive Letter Manager is one of them](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html).

You can also mount an external USB Drive as a '`Folder`' on your windows system
(rather than allocate it a drive letter) -- some [quick notes on that](http://www.watchingthenet.com/mount-partition-as-folder-in-windows.html).

Some more notes also at HowToGeek: [Find Your Missing USB Drive on Windows XP](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/find-your-missing-usb-drive-on-windows-xp/)