# How to ensure that a USB HDD mounts to a specific drive letter, without using "USB Drive Letter Manager"?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make an external hard drive keep the same drive letter permanently?](https://superuser.com/questions/98924/how-do-i-make-an-external-hard-drive-keep-the-same-drive-letter-permanently)
>   [Unable to make USB drive letter stick](https://superuser.com/questions/36832/unable-to-make-usb-drive-letter-stick)
>   [Force a USB device to use a certain drive letter](https://superuser.com/questions/70295/force-a-usb-device-to-use-a-certain-drive-letter)

I have to ensure that a USB HDD mounts to a specific drive letter if pluged in.

This may seem a duplicate of many other questions, but I can't use [USBDLM](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm.html) (*USB Drive Letter Manager*) on the host machine. An autorun batch would be great. Or can you help me writing a c# autorun app for my problem?

Comment: See "Force a USB device to use a certain drive letter" at http://superuser.com/questions/70295/force-a-usb-device-to-use-a-certain-drive-letter, or "Unable to make USB drive letter stick" at http://superuser.com/questions/36832/unable-to-make-usb-drive-letter-stick, or "How do I make an external hard drive keep the same drive letter permanently?" at http://superuser.com/questions/98924/how-do-i-make-an-external-hard-drive-keep-the-same-drive-letter-permanently, or...

Comment: "I can't use USBDLM." ... I know how to do this manualy, but i'm looking for an automated way to do this.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was too easily triggered by the migration from Stack Overflow. The other questions *do* list other options though. Apart from that USBDLM, what else does not work? (And I assume an autorun file on the drive itself would run *after* Windows has mapped the drive?)

Comment: yeah probably, but you can change the drive letter any time manualy so i think this should be possible by code/script.

Comment: @Arjan: the only "other option" I see mentioned at the three "duplicates" you list is "do it manually".

Answer (score 1):

In Windows I believe you can set that in the control panel, system administration, computer management, removable storage. (I'm translating here so yours might be slightly different)

You could make a reg dump, configure your own system so it does that, make another reg dump and see what's changed. That registry change you could import using a batch file or something.

I don't usually work with windows anymore, but that's what I remember :)

A windows registry dump can be made with, for example, regedit. (choose export)

Also have a look at [this post](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/18087-reassigning-drive-letters-automatically/) which may describe what you want.

Comment: reg dump of what?

Comment: I know how to make a reg dump ... but the problem is that if i make a full reg dump i end up with 2 reg dumps 300MB each ... and WinMerge fails to open this files ... so i can't find the diff

Comment: Use a command line tool like diff might be a better option then.